# dynamic radio button layout not work

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to make a dynamic radio button to linear layout. I have two radio buttons which are called from List and added to Linear Layout. Everything works fine until I get bad looks at my radio button and get stuck with this layout. My question is why does my radio button layout not work at all?

Here is my code :

```
TextView label;
RadioButton[] rb;
RadioGroup radiogroup;
LinearLayout ll;
String title;

public MyBtn(Context context,String labelText,String options) {
   super(context);

   ll = new LinearLayout(context);
   ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
       LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

   ll.setLayoutParams(params);

   label = new TextView(context);
   label.setText(labelText);
   label.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.label_color));

   radiogroup = new RadioGroup(context);
   radiogroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);

   radiogroup.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams [] rbLayout = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams[2]; 

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams  rbParam = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
         RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   rbParam.weight = 1f;
   rbParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT;

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams  rbParam2 = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
         RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   rbParam2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT;
   rbParam2.weight = 1f;

   rbLayout[0] = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(rbParam);                  
   rbLayout[1] = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(rbParam2);

   List<String> list = Arrays.asList(options.split("\\|"));
   String[] opts = new String[list.size()];
   list.toArray(opts);

   rb = new RadioButton[list.size()];

   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      rb[i] = new RadioButton(context);
      rb[i].setText(opts[i]);
      rb[i].setId(i);
      radiogroup.addView(rb[i],rbLayout[i]);         
   }

   title = label.getText().toString();

   radiogroup.check(0);

   ll.addView(label);
   ll.addView(radiogroup);

   //int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", context.getPackageName());  

   this.addView(ll); 
}
```

Thank you.

My radio button :

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvAGf.jpg)


It should :

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmjnM.jpg)

Comment: The current wording of your question is very difficult to understand. Can you please revise your question?

Comment: sorry for my bad words, the question is radio button layout named rblayout in this line not work _radiogroup.addView(rb[i],rbLayout[i]);_ thank you

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams [] rbLayout = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams[2];
LinearLayout.LayoutParams  rbParam2 = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
     RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

to this:

```
RadioGroup.LayoutParams [] rbLayout = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams[2];
RadioGroup.LayoutParams  rbParam2 = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
     RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

there are many same mistake in your code. find out them and correct
let me know about result

---

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams  rbParam = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
     RadioGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);
```

that must work.
let me know about it